# Using Django template tags in a modal window

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the Django comments app in my modal diagram, specifically the tag:

```
    {% comments item %}
```

Which brings up a place for users to submit comments and view comments on a model object (in my case the variable is called `item`).

Is it possible to use this in a modal window, and if so, how? I imagine it would need javascript/jquery to pass the variables, etc. but have no idea where to start on that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why using tags in a modal window would be any different to using them anywhere else. Either your window is built alongside the elements in the existing page, in which case you use template tags there, or its built via Ajax, in which case you use template tags when you render the Ajax response.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think the problem may be that because `item` is a variable dependent on what I click on. Is there a way to replace the `item` part in `{% comments item %}` in the modal?